# Evolution override gconftool-2 modification

Tags: 12.04, evolution, gconf

We are in "beta-test" at my job to install some Ubuntu (12.04 LTS) on the network and we've got a little problem. We try to "standardize" as much as we can (with script when possible) and in the case of Evolution (3.2, still on gconf right?) we run into a problem. For example, if we try to enable "Send as HTML" option with the command below :

```
$gconftool-2 --set --type=bool /apps/evolution/mail/composer/send_html true
```

After that we do a **--get** of that option to see if the parameter is ok (we receive *true*)

```
$gconftool-2 --get /apps/evolution/mail/composer/send_html
true
```

BUT as soon as we open Evolution, the parameter is overwritten and return to *false*

I don't know if it's just my collegue and me who doesn't know how gconftool-2 works or something else. Anyway, if you could help us I would be **very** grateful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FIY, I found the solution...and I was dumb!

gconf modifications doesn't take effect immediatly in most case. You have various options (from what I've learned) :

1. Do your modification with the user session closed
2. Log off then on after your modification
3. If you want your change to take effect "live", you can send a SIGHUP signal to gconfd daemon. You can use the command below :

`ps -eF | grep gconfd | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}' | sudo xargs kill -1`

In the case of Evolution, be sure to restart Evolution to be sure that change take effect.

Hope I help newbies like me!